# Can't get this regular expression to extract my capturing groups

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know that google-apps-script doesn't fully support regular expressions. But on my other functions, it extracted what I was looking for. So it seems I'm missing something here.

```
var teststring = "E37:E61";
var regExp = /\w+(\d+)\:\w+(\d+)/; // no i or g needed here as fas as I think
var extractedNumbers = regExp.exec(teststring);
```

**Output:**

```
[E37:E61, 7, 1]
```

**What I've also tested:**

```
var teststring = "E37:E61";
var regExp = new RegExp(/\w+(\d+)\:\w+(\d+)/); // Note that '' are not working I had to use //
var extractedNumbers = regExp.exec(teststring);
```

**Output:**

```
null
```

**Additionally tested:**

```
var regExp = /\w+(\d+)\:\w+(\d+)/;
var rowsToFill = teststring.match(regExp);
```

**Output:**

```
[E37:E61, 7, 1]
```

**What I'm looking for is:**

```
[37, 61]
```

Comment: Just so that you're aware, now that GAS has moved to the V8 runtime, support for regular expressions has improved considerably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should mind that `\w` matches digits.

Use `[^\W\d]` to match any word chars but digits, or just `[a-zA-Z_]`:

```js
var teststring = "E37:E61";
var regExp = /[^\W\d]+(\d+):[^\W\d]+(\d+)/; 
var extractedNumbers = regExp.exec(teststring);
console.log(extractedNumbers);
// => [ "E37:E61", "37", "61" ]
```

Comment: Oh my god. So embarrassed, looking at that for hours and missing the fact that `\w` includes word chars, shouldn't code that late. Thanks for your fast feedback and for helping me to find what I overlooked.

Comment: @BenjaminK You have not specified the exact format of the strings you deal with, thus, I suggested taking the `\d` out of `\w`. If you explicitly mentioned the format is *ASCII uppercase letters followed with digits, `:`, ASCII uppercase letters followed with digits*, I'd have suggested `/[A-Z]+(\d+):[A-Z]+(\d+)/`. My answer is directly answering your *it seems I'm missing something here* doubt.

Comment: Given the tags, it's highly unlikely that it refers to anything other than ``[A-Z]`` as it is a range string. `[a-z]` is also likely in Google sheets, but I've never seen apps script return a lowercase range string.  But `[^\W\d]` double negative combo is nice.

Answer (score 3):

`\w` includes digits. Use a more specific regexp

```js
var teststring = "E37:E61";
var regExp = /[A-Z]+(\d+)\:[A-Z]+(\d+)/; // no i or g needed here as fas as I think
var extractedNumbers = regExp.exec(teststring);
console.info(extractedNumbers)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will go with that as it's the easiest to read! Still can't believe I overlooked `\w` hast numbers included.

Comment: @Ben Consider accepting the answer(or any other answer provided)

Answer (score 1):

Regex patterns match greedily from left to right. This is why `\w` (which includes digits, see the other answers) matches `E3` and `E6` (he respective second digit is not matched as in this case the complete regex could no longer match).

Next to the remedies the other contributors suggested you could also switch to non-greedy matching in the proper subexpressions:

```js
var teststring = "E37:E61";
var regExp = /\w+?(\d+)\:\w+?(\d+)/; // quantifiers '+'/'*' suffixed with '?' match non-greedily
var extractedNumbers = regExp.exec(teststring);
console.log(extractedNumbers);
// => [ "E37:E61", "37", "61" ]
```